# More than half of my meshes are invisible since the upgrade, and I can't bring them into view

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

I recently updated the blender, and while I like the new look, many of the elements I have come to know and rely on have been vastly altered or re-arranged. That's okay, I'm relearning, but almost all of my client work is hidden, invisible, IDK. As you can see the visibility is set to eye open. When I copy and paste the element it displays correctly, which is one workaround, but my file is literally thousands of meshes it would be very challenging to recopy and repaste every image.

[image: Please assist]

Comment: Could be disabled in viewport. Have a look at the filter menu/button on top right of the outliner.

Comment: Sometimes you need to think of the Eye Open as just an indicator of crazed shock in Blender.  Please also investigate the View Object Types options with the eye icon  in the 3D View.  Some of these can make invisible whole classes of objects.  You can also display more info in the outliner by changing its options with the menu with the funnel icon Filter Restrictions.  These clearly operate on each individual object.  I had a problem with lattice details recently.  Copy and Paste is not reasonable at all.